# How Android Studio will work as Notepad to stop auto correction/import/others setting

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm learning android and using Android Studio. I'm hate when android studio do bunch of code by self. Android studio importing self and correcting me during typing that is not good for me to remember some code or libraries. I want to disable all auto correction and importing of android studio so it's editor will work as Notepad. But and want to get error only during compiling.

I want to do this, because I learn java by notepad that's why I remembered a lot of code and libraries.

After learning android, I will back to it for developing apps to save the time.

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Editor > Java and then turn off whatever you want.

Or you can do something like this:

```
// @formatter:off
...
// @formatter:on
```

Comment: Zahid just one more question, should I learn Android 7.0 ? Mean should I create project on 7.0?

Comment: It doesn't matter :) // @formatter:off is IDE annotation.

Comment: I'm asking for learning purpose. Mean should I start learning by creating project in android 7.0?

Comment: Yeah sure. You can do that as you don't need to have a real device and you can just use an emulator. BUT it won't be a good idea to use android 7.0 if you want to make an app which has a larger audience. If you're really newbie, then it would be a good idea but if you're planning to make an app you need to learn how to use Support libraries and then decide a target sdk :)

Answer (score 0):

You can go to `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion` and disable `Autopopup code completion`, which would get you most of the way to the experience you're looking for, and if you need any help while coding you can always use `Ctrl+Space` to manually invoke code completion.

As for importing, you can find settings in `Editor -> General -> Auto Import`.

Comment: should I create project in android 7.0?